# Native query setParameter difference

Tags: nativequery

Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM IS_CON \n"
                    + "WHERE CONNUMBER=?1 AND REV=?2", IsCon.class).setParameter(1, con).setParameter(2, rev);
 is query return null.

But this query works.

Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM IS_CON \n"
                    + "WHERE CONNUMBER='"+con+"' AND REV='"+rev+"'", IsCon.class);

What is wrong my code? I think my code has nothing wrong.

Comment: What are the values (and Java types) for `con` and `rev` that you put in? What are the respective entity property and database column types?

Comment: Tanks Thilo. String con ; Short rev; I think that issue is some of settings. But i don't know how i fix. setParameter() method don't set parameters in my query.

Comment: String con = "1205034252";
        Short rev = 0;